# understanding how hbase uses hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I’m trying to understand how hbase uses the hdfs.
so here is what I understand (please correct me if I'm wrong):
I know that hbase use hdfs to store data and that data is split into regions, and that each region server my serve many regions,so I guess that one region (exclusively) may communicate with many data node to get and put data, so If that is correct then if that region server fails then data stored in those data node, will not be accessible anymore 
thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a Regionserver runs on a datanode.

Due to how HDFS works, the Regionserver will perform its reads and writes to the local datanode when possible, and then HDFS will ensure that the data is replicated onto two other random datanodes. So at all times, the data written by that regionserver is stored on 3 nodes in HDFS.

While a regionserver is serving a region, only it will read / write the data for that region, but if the regionserver process crashes, the HBase master will select another regionsever to serve that region. The data will be unavailable for a few minutes, but HBase will recover quickly.

If the entire host fails, then as HDFS ensured the data was written onto two other nodes, the scenario is the same - the master will select a new regionserver to open the failed region and the data not be lost.

Comment: and of the three data node (used for replication), the region server communicate(or use ) only one data node

Comment: For reads, normally yes. For writes, the write will goto 1 DN and then be replicated by HDFS to the others. If a region fails and is started on a new host, then it is likely that host does not have the required data locally, so then the Regionserver will talk to other nodes in the cluster to read the data. So in that scenario, it could talk to any of the other datanodes in the cluster

Comment: @StephenODonnell Will data locality be reestablished after a major compaction?

Comment: Yes, after a major compaction the data should all be on the local node again. Each minor compaction will slowly build up the locality too, but it will require a major compaction to fully restore it.